# How to change at runtime the value of SMsgDlgYes, SMsgDlgNo, etc

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How can I change/translate at runtime the value of [`resourcestring`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resource_Strings) `const`s like `SMsgDlgYes`, `SMsgDlgNo`, etc. as used by `TDialogService.MessageDialog`?

It's for a FireMonkey app (iOS/Android/Windows) so I can't use Windows API like [`VirtualProtect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: In theory, you should be able to use TLang and the Language Designer (double click the TLang component on your form to open it). Unfortunately, I can't find any examples or documentation on how to use it or the proper format of the .lng files that it's apparently using; it breaks on trying to use any of the .lng files I've been able to find, which are apparently for Windows. You're supposed to be able to just set the TLang.Lang to the two-letter language code after setting up the translations, and it does all the rest.

Comment: thanks ken ... no i study deeply the source code, their is no way to translate the SMsgDlgYes :( i just added a feature request to emb :  https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15970

Comment: What should be changed is MsgTitles[] and ButtonCaptions[]. Those are consts. They should be vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the search for how to make the switch to the ButtonCaptions and after giving myself almost up, I found an easy way. That I share.
In my case I use the call to TDialogServiceAsync.MessageDialog, to show an asynchronous message in Android, but before making the call I personalize the ButtonCaptions, which is nothing more than a constant defined in FMX.Dialogs that when typed allows to redefine it

```
ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbyes] := 'Si';
      TDialogServiceAsync.MessageDialog(‘Está seguro de salir sin guardar?’,
        TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation,
        [TMsgDlgBtn.mbyes,TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo],
        TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo,
        0,
        procedure(const AResult:TModalResult)
         begin
           if AResult = mrYes then
            begin
               //put our code
            end
             else begin
              //put our code
            end;
         end
        );
```

Comment: This does not compile for me.  first line gives error 'Left side cannot be assigned to'. I tried to use {$WRITEABLECONST ON} but I guess this must be done in the const declaration in FMX.Dialogs.pas. So I guess one has to change the FMX file (ie.copy FMX.Dialogs.pas do project directory and then change)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on raudel.s.j answer, I found that changing constant ButtonCaptions[] did not work (at least for Android). So I copyed FMX.Dialogs.pas to my project directory and changed the **const** to a **var**

FMX.Dialogs.pas

```
    ..
  var  // <-- added this to change ButtonCaptions and MsgTitles to var, to allow localization
    MsgTitles: array[TMsgDlgType] of string = (SMsgDlgWarning, SMsgDlgError, SMsgDlgInformation, SMsgDlgConfirm, '');
    ButtonCaptions: array[TMsgDlgBtn] of string = (SMsgDlgYes, SMsgDlgNo, SMsgDlgOK, SMsgDlgCancel, SMsgDlgAbort,    
    ...
```

then I added:

```
Procedure LocalizeDialogButtons; // localize texts inside FMX.Dialogs
begin
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbyes]      := Translate(SMsgDlgYes);        //  'Yes'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbno]       := Translate(SMsgDlgNo);         //  'No'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK]       := Translate(SMsgDlgOK);         //  'OK'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbCancel]   := Translate(SMsgDlgCancel);     //  'Cancel'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbAbort]    := Translate(SMsgDlgAbort);      //  'Abort'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbRetry]    := Translate(SMsgDlgRetry);      //  'Retry'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbIgnore]   := Translate(SMsgDlgIgnore);     //  'Ignore'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbNoToAll]  := Translate(SMsgDlgNoToAll);    //  'No to All'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbYesToAll] := Translate(SMsgDlgYesToAll);   //  'Yes to &All'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbHelp]     := Translate(SMsgDlgHelp);       //  'Help'
  ButtonCaptions[TMsgDlgBtn.mbClose]    := Translate(SMsgDlgClose);      //  'All'
  MsgTitles[TMsgDlgType.mtWarning]      := Translate(SMsgDlgWarning);    //  'Warning'
  MsgTitles[TMsgDlgType.mtError]        := Translate(SMsgDlgError);      //  'Error'
  MsgTitles[TMsgDlgType.mtInformation]  := Translate(SMsgDlgInformation);//  'Information'
  MsgTitles[TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation] := Translate(SMsgDlgConfirm);    //  'Confirm'

end;
```

Which is called on FormCreate, after loading the localization strings with TLang.

Add the dialog texts to TLang (one by one).
Complete the translations for the new texts, for all languages. 
So all text translations are in one place.

Note that you *have to* compare your changed FMX.Dialogs.pas with the official version (and apply changes) every time you do a Delphi update, to be in sync

Comment: A complete solution for using TLang can be found at: 
https://github.com/omarreis/LangTool/